# «Своим(,) настоящим(,) именем представляться надо!»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация, уточнения, однородные-неоднородные-определения

1. Своим, настоящим, именем представляться надо!
2. Своим, настоящим именем представляться надо!
3. Своим настоящим именем представляться надо!

Как правильно?

Comment: своим - отвечает на вопрос "Чьим", настоящее - это прилагательное, именем - сущ. Следовательно, можно заменить более простыми словами (пусть и бессмысленными) для понимания: моим красным лаком. Тут не нужна запятая. Потому, что нет перечислений и сложносочинённых конструкций. Полагаю, правильный ответ - 3.

Comment: Вторая запятая обычно ставится, когда во втором определении больше одного слова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ***Своим, настоящим, именем представляться надо!***

Этот вариант, как мне кажется, выглядит «нежизнеспособным». Можно, наверное, притянуть сюда правило из параграфа «[Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#)» (справочник Розенталя):

> Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений ***этот, тот, такой, каждый, один*** (в значении местоимения) и т. п.

Трудно сказать, относится ли местоименное прилагательное [***свой***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x) (принадлежащий или свойственный себе) к «и т. п.». Своим может быть и ненастоящее, выдуманное имя.
Вторая запятая после уточнения должна, пусть еле заметно, обозначать паузу. Но в этом экспрессивном, с восклицательным знаком, предложении так не прочитаешь.

2. ***СвоИм, настоЯщим именем представляться надо!***

При такой пунктуации делается два логических ударения, есть явная пауза. То есть определения становятся однородными, отчасти синонимичными, второе из которых поясняет первое, а мысль автора выражается в том, что он считает ненастоящее имя не принадлежащим своему собеседнику.

3. ***Своим настоЯщим именем представляться надо!***

Одно ударение, нет паузы (интонация «не задерживается» на ***своим***), и нет никакого диссонанса в понимании смысловых отношений между определениями и их значений.
*Это **моё** настоящее имя, а это **моё** ненастоящее имя.*

И действительно, в Нацкорпусе словосочетание «[своё настоящее имя](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CuECEr4CCrsCElsKEQoDbGV4EgoKCNGB0LLQvtC1CgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACgsKBWdyYW1tEgIKAAoJCgNzZW0SAgoAChUKB3NlbS1tb2QSCgoIc2VtfHNlbXgKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAEnMKGwoDbGV4EhQKEtC90LDRgdGC0L7Rj9GJ0LXQtQoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKAAoMCgRkaXN0IgQIARABEmcKDwoDbGV4EggKBtC40LzRjwoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKAAoMCgRkaXN0IgQIARABKhcKCAgAEAoYMiAKIAAoyKPu3t%2BA5wZABTICCAE6AQEwAQ%3D%3D)» в разных падежах встречается только без запятых.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Александр!

Answer (score 1):

Помнится, у Д.Розенталя я читал правило о том, что определения, характеризующие определяемое слово с разных сторон, являются однородными, если второе  определение поясняет первое. Там приводился запоминающийся пример: "Я построил новый, каменный дом" (имеется в виду, что старый дом был не каменный). Исходя из этого, правильный вариант в Вашем случае: "Своим, настоящим именем представляться надо!"

Comment: Я бы и 2-й вариант, и 3-й использовала. В Нацкорпусе (ruscorpora.ru) - только 3-й! Вот как бы 3-й вариант ещё объяснить (когда мы пояснения не видим), чтобы ответ получился полным? Т.е. как объяснить, что в одном случае МЫ ВИДИМ ПОЯСНЕНИЕ И ЗАПЯТУЮ СТАВИМ, но можем это пояснение там же НЕ ВИДЕТЬ, А ПОЭТОМУ ЗАПЯТУЮ УЖЕ НЕ СТАВИМ?

Comment: Розенталь: Так называемые пояснительные определения однородными не являются.